# Is there any search algorithm that finds out a specific key(hint) and data related to it in a file efficiently?

Tags: algorithm

I have to write a logger class in PHP. I will save all my logs in file because I don't want to overload the database server. The only problem is that, I don't know how to efficiently search for logs saved in a file on a specific date (or between two dates). Is there an algorithm to pull out data efficiently by taking a hint (i.e. date) as input? There may be a million of logs in a file. In that case, it is very important to efficiently search for logs inserted on a given date (or between two dates).

Comment: Could you save one log file per day with filenames like "2016-04-22.log"? That would also make it easier to archive old logs into a zip file.

Comment: That would be a lot of files and thus a nightmare if I ever try to physically browse the logs folder and find the logs. I want to log everything inside a single log file.

Comment: It's only 365 (or 366) files per year, and you could organise them into directories by year and month. With one large file, if it gets corrupted then you could lose the whole lot. Reading logs from previous dates could be awkward as the system is still trying to write to the file. Backing it up could be awkward too. Log file fragmentation could become an issue. Eventually the log file will outgrow the available disk space. But it's your choice in the end. You could use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: I would do it like @AndrewMorton. And if you write a lot, then even make directories for the days and a file per hour. Then you could also automatically archive your files by making yearly or monthly zip files.